# Windows 10 Compatibility mode not working for Windows Live Mail

Tags: windows-10, email, compatibility

I have an old HDD connected to my PC and that HDD has Windows 7 installed with Windows Live Mail. I would like to run the Windows Live Mail that's in there, so I can export some emails to Outlook. Problem is when I set the `wlmail.exe` to Windows 7 compatibility mode it just crashes. I can see `KERNELBASE.dll` in the Windows logs as part of the crash log.

How can I run Windows Live Mail under Windows 10 2004?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Live Mail is definitely not supported on Windows 10 in any recent version of Windows 10.

You need to export the WLM mail to an Outlook PST file. If you cannot get Windows 7 working, you have two options:

1. Make a Windows 7 Virtual Machine and use Windows Live Mail in the virtual machine to export the file.
2. Use the Windows Live Mail to Outlook Converter by SysTools to convert the WLM files to Outlook.

https://technewskb.com/convert-windows-live-mail-to-outlook-pst/

Look down the page for "Alternative Solution"

> If in case user does not want to go for the manual methods to convert
> WLM files to Outlook they can use Windows Live Mail to Outlook
> Converter by SysTools to easily migrate WLM emails to MS Outlook,
> which is much easier and user-friendly.

Comment: I tried many tools already, the problem is the user (my uncle) had A LOT of folders and Outlook isn't migrating the folders, it's really weird, it add one folder with a name like `Windows Live Mail` and inside some folders, but not all, and then I can't delete those folders, it just gives an error, so I have a bunch of failed imports folders, and those folders aren't even inside `Inbox`.

Comment: If feasible, you may wish to try a Windows 7 VM and retry the Live Mail export.

Comment: That's my next step.